# Terraform - Why a state file is required?

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Before Plan and Apply, terraform always refreshes the state file.
Then what is the real need for the state file?

If it is required to keep track of the resources that were created by IaC, it can just keep the IDs of the resources. Why a detailed state?

Comment: As an exercise I suggest creating something simple with terraform, deleting the state file and then running apply again without changing anything in the terraform code. Also, please take a look here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Terraform has a very general design so that it can support as many different remote systems as possible. While it's true that lots of remote objects have an obvious single ID which uniquely identifies them, there are some remote object types which are uniquely identified by a combination of values and even some cases where the entire configuration acts as the identity of the object.

Also some remote systems have write-only attributes which the provider would have no way to recover if they were not saved in the Terraform state.

The state file includes a verbatim copy of the entire object that the provider returned after the most recent action, and then when planning the next action Terraform sends that entire object back to the provider. The provider itself then decides what subset of that data to use to determine which remote object this resource instance represents.

For many resource types you'll find that if you directly edit the state snapshots to remove everything except the `id` attribute then the provider will still successfully refresh the object and repopulate all of the other data you removed, but that isn't always true. Terraform itself doesn't know what a provider will need to do its work, and so it always just stores the entire object.

Although that core problem of Terraform not knowing what is and is not significant is the original driver, the fact that Terraform stores the entire object has some other benefits:

- A provider can, in most cases, detect if an object has been changed outside of Terraform and add an additional note to the plan if that might help explain why the provider is proposing to undo that change.

  Having this third source of data to compare against gives Terraform a hint about whether a mismatch between the remote system and the configuration was caused by changing the configuration or by changing the remote system.
- Extra features like `terraform console` and `terraform show` can allow inspecting the object data without having to re-fetch everything from the source system.

  Terraform could in principle go and refresh all of the data again from the remote API, but since Terraform is already storing a copy of the data anyway it's faster (and therefore more convenient when debugging) to return that copy of the data.

There's more information in the official documentation section [Purpose of Terraform State](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/purpose).